# Pine Script Orders Repeated

Tags: pine-script

I am using 3rd Party Binance Order Execution Bridge.

My Order Logic is simple. as follows

```
strategy.entry("Long "+TickerS, strategy.long, stop=open[1]-(syminfo.mintick), when = strategy.opentrades==0, comment=OrderComment)
```

Backtest is fine. but when doing forward testing, PineScript Issues three Alerts for the same order. Wondering what is wrong.

Comment: Well, show us how you trigger the alerts.

Comment: My Long Condition as follows:   GoLong=( close[1]>open[1] and close>close[1] )

Answer (score 0):

I have found that this error is coming from TradingView.  I have open a support ticket and waiting for their response.

To be sure  what I did is opened a Free Trial Account and tested the same script and logic on new trial account. I found, the Alerts are generating as they should be and no repeat Alerts were generated.